# Resolver issue?

Tags: linux, centos, dns

i own a dedicated server. my hosting providers resolver ip's are not working / pingable. As an alternative i am temporarily using Google IP's to resolve website server. But resolving is too slow with my server.

Because resolvers are not fast, some of the website services such as email server, captcha and php services requiring the use of resolver is either slow or not working.

How to fix resolvers? Can running my own dns server help?

Comment: Please add the entire contents of your `/etc/resolv.conf` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Contact your hosting company and asks them why their recursive nameservers do not work. Maybe they've changed their IP addresses and you did not have the information. Or you may have on overzealous firewall on your server filtering things. In any case `ping` is not a valid tool to troubleshoot DNS issues, use `dig`. So start by some new troubleshooting tests.

Also, running a local recursive nameserver on your dedicated server will give you a lot of benefits (and you can configure it to forward to your webhosting company nameservers first and only as a second option to do the resolution by themselves), but please make sure to configure it to reply only on `127.0.0.1` and `::1` in order for it not to be available from outside of your dedicated server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your own local DNS server could be more responsive.

Are you looking up names of your local infrastructure that could be in /etc/hosts?

Comment: Public dns server not the local one

Comment: 'local' as in running one on the same network or on the localhost's 127.0.0.1 address. Both should respond quicker than the remote DNS server. There are also some other things to consider, if 8.8.8.8 (google's) is in a different country to you then the response that you get back may be tailored to the country that 8.8.8.8 happens to be in, and not where the query originated (your machine).

Comment: @EdNeville `8.8.8.8` is an anycast server so it could easily be in several (many) places.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you query your DNS provider rather than ping'ing it:

```
~$ nslookup example.com 8.8.8.8
```

'example.com' is an actual site.

Investigate your hosting provider DNS server using the command above, and do the same with different provider (I advice you to stick with google **8.8.8.8** / **8.8.4.4**).

Then, if you could supply the file `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Implementing your own local DNS server that caches the request and listen on port 53/UDP is an option, but do you want the extra headache on maintenance the service, so only one server will benefit from? Let's us investigate then if we had some good information we might just inform the hosting provider to fix it :).

Comment: It would be better if you use `dig` for troubleshooting instead of `nslookup` :-)

Comment: Hello @PatrickMevzek, `dig` require more complicated syntax and more output that need to be explained, that what I thought